# Does the [load] tag need to exist?

Tags: discussion, tags

It seems like one of those tags that can't stand on their own. Who would follow it? What's its *raison d'être*?

Answer (score -2):

It's true that it wont stand on it's own. However, the poster has options to add more tags and readers would be able to interpret the context in which it's applied based on the other tags.